# How to have even height for all input fields

Tags: html, css

I have designed a contact form with HTML and CSS. I have added a `small` tag under each input to show errors. If one field has an error the other field is pushed down a bit.

You can also see the form live [here](https://lunch.pk/dev/muslimabc/contact)

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-fields {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: 'name email' 'subject phone' 'message message';
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.form-fields .input {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  border-color: #f2f3f5;
}

.form-fields .name-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: name;
}

.form-fields .email-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: email;
}

.form-fields .subject-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: subject;
}

.form-fields .phone-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: phone;
}

.form-fields .message-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-area: message;
}

.form-fields .message-field .input {
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-fields">
  <div class="form-group name-field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger">some error for this input</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group email-field">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group subject-field">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group phone-field">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group message-field">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="message" class="input form-control"></textarea>
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `align-items: center;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-fields {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: 'name email' 'subject phone' 'message message';
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
         
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.form-fields .input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.75rem 0.75rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.text-danger {
    color: #f64e60;
}
.form-fields .name-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: name;
}

.form-fields .email-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: email;
}

.form-fields .subject-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: subject;
}

.form-fields .phone-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: phone;
}

.form-fields .message-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-area: message;
}

.form-fields .message-field .input {
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-fields">
  <div class="form-group name-field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger">some error for this input</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group email-field">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group subject-field">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group phone-field">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group message-field">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="message" class="input form-control"></textarea>
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've used the small tag, which means that it is `1.83em` tall. We can then work out the size of the inputs, add them together, and then set that for the height of the `.form-group` class.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-fields {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: 'name email' 'subject phone' 'message message';
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.form-fields .input {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  border-color: #f2f3f5;
}

.form-fields .name-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: name;
}

.form-fields .email-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: email;
}

.form-fields .subject-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: subject;
}

.form-fields .phone-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: phone;
}

.form-fields .message-field {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-area: message;
}

.form-fields .message-field .input {
  height: 120px;
}
.form-group {
   height: calc(0.875rem + 1.83em);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-fields">
  <div class="form-group name-field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger">some error for this input</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group email-field">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group subject-field">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group phone-field">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="input form-control" />
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group message-field">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="message" class="input form-control"></textarea>
    <small class="text-danger"></small>
  </div>
</div>
```